# Is the statement grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Is the bold part of the following statement grammatically correct?

> Let $A$ be the set of all cycles in $B$ which their lengths **are
>   congruent to $i$ modulo 7.**

Comment: That appears to be a relative clause, and it appears to be ungrammatical. But it might not be, because only this part has been shown, and not its context. The context is important, since relative clauses are subordinate, and the main clause governs everything.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: This is now proofreading. "Is it correct?" In order for it not to be proof-reading, you need to point out where you believe it might be wrong.

Comment: Hint: *whose*..

Comment: @AndrewLeach This statement : "...are congruent to $i$ modulo 7".

Comment: OK: That's shown in the question. Could you add why you believe it to be wrong? The community is rather strict about proof-reading "Is this correct" questions.

Answer (score 1):

The bold part is correct...  But the first part is not.

Maybe

> Let $A$ be the set of all cycles in $B$ whose lengths are congruent to $i$ modulo 7.

or

> Let $A$ be the set of all cycles in $B$ with length congruent to $i$ modulo 7.

Comment: but are *lengths* really congruent or are they just *equal*?

Comment: really congruent!